# Create missing file in all subdirs with ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

I want to check if there is a specific file in all subdirs of a folder. If the file doesn't exists, I want to create it.
This is my playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: 'yes'
  vars:
    dir_path: "/tmp/test"
  tasks:
  - name: Find /tmp/test/ all directories
    find:
      paths: /tmp/test/
      recurse: no
      file_type: directory
    register: dir_list
  - debug: var=dir_list
  - name: check if test file exists
    stat:
      path:  "{{ dir_list.files | map(attribute='path') }}/test.txt"
    register:  file_exists
    loop: "{{ dir_list.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
  - name: create file
    shell: touch {{ files_exists.item }}/test.txt
    register: create_file
    when: not file_exists.stat.exists
    loop: "{{ file_exists.item }} | list }}"
```

But the "create file" fails, any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Post the error. [edit] the question and make it [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `loop` in the last tasks is wrong: you are not using the `item` created during iteration when checking for file existence.

(Note for your next question: avoid using sentences like "it fails" or "it doesn't work" on their own as [they do not accurately describe your problem](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/))

In your example, you are trying to create the file with `shell` when there is a `file` module made just for that purpose. I used it my below example:

The playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Create missing file in subdirs
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    dir_path: "/tmp/test"
    file_name: "test.txt"

  tasks:
    - name: "Find subdirs in {{ dir_path }}"
      find:
        paths: "{{ dir_path }}"
        recurse: no
        file_type: directory
      register: dir_list

    - name: "Show result of dir listing "
      debug:
        var: dir_list
        verbosity: 1

    - name: "Check if {{ file_name }} exists in subdirs"
      stat:
        path: "{{ item }}/{{ file_name }}"
      register: file_check
      loop: "{{ dir_list.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"

    - name: "Show the file check result"
      debug:
        var: file_check
        verbosity: 1

    - name: "Create file where it does not exist"
      file:
        path: "{{ item }}/{{ file_name }}"
        state: touch
      loop: "{{ file_check.results | rejectattr('stat.exists') | map(attribute='item') | list }}"
```

Which gives (use `ansible-playbook -v` to see `verbosity: 1` debug tasks)

```
# Create test dir and subdirs
$ for d in {a..d}; do mkdir -p /tmp/test/$d; done

# Add the test file in one dir for demo
$ touch /tmp/test/c/test.txt

# Show the situation before running the playbook
$ tree /tmp/test/
/tmp/test/
├── a
├── b
├── c
│   └── test.txt
└── d

4 directories, 1 file

# Run the playbook (run with debug for yourself if you wish)
$ ansible-playbook play.yml

PLAY [Create missing file in subdirs] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Find subdirs in /tmp/test] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show result of dir listing] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Check if test.txt exists in subdirs] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/a)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/b)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/c)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/d)

TASK [Show the file check result] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Create file where it does not exist] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/a)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/b)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/d)

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0

# Check the result
$ tree /tmp/test/
/tmp/test/
├── a
│   └── test.txt
├── b
│   └── test.txt
├── c
│   └── test.txt
└── d
    └── test.txt

4 directories, 4 files

# Run the playbook again to demonstrate idempotency
$ ansible-playbook play.yml

PLAY [Create missing file in subdirs] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Find subdirs in /tmp/test] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show result of dir listing] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Check if test.txt exists in subdirs] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/a)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/b)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/c)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test/d)

TASK [Show the file check result] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Create file where it does not exist] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Hi, when I execute this, I receive this error: 

TASK [Check if test.txt exists in subdirs] **********************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/je90506/ansible/playbooks/test_subdir3.yml:23
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: <generator object do_map at 0x7f3a9005b5f0>. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."
}

Comment: Just edited so that the solution works in both ansible < and >= 2.10. See the `| list` in the loop expressions.

Comment: I have solved it to add | list to the loop function. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If this solves your issue, consider accepting the answer (green tick) so other users know there is a working solution.